# Mouse position Controlled by ViewList

Tags: c#

so I have this Window Application that simulates mouse movement, I made a few tests and managed to "record" mouse movement and play it once recorded. Now I wanna make a Viewlist with 2 columns ("X" and "Y) containing the coords of the route I want my mouse to follow. Coordinates can be added throught "ycoord" and "xcoord"  textlabels and can be added with "button1" button to the viewlist. There's also a "button2" that works as a "toggle" button to turn it on and off. So, I want is that, every time I press left click form mouse (LButton) the movement runs as long as I hold this button, and, if I hold it again it starts over again. I already managed the textlabels to place content into the viewlist, but I don't know how to read the viewlist and convert them into mouse movement coords.
[image]

Thanks in advance for the help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to save the X,Y coords in a List, so you can create a list of points, then you have to iterate it and use it with:

Look at the object `Cursor` [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.cursor.current.aspx)

Also you have the code:

```
private void MoveCursor()
{
   // Set the Current cursor, move the cursor's Position,
   // and set its clipping rectangle to the form. 

   this.Cursor = new Cursor(Cursor.Current.Handle);
   Cursor.Position = new Point(Cursor.Position.X - 50, Cursor.Position.Y - 50);
   Cursor.Clip = new Rectangle(this.Location, this.Size);
}
```

Try this:

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        private List<Point> _points = null;

        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            _points = new List<Point>();

            this.MouseMove += Form1_MouseMove;
        }

        private void Form1_MouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
        {
            //Save the point
            _points.Add(new Point(e.X, e.Y));
        }

        private void PerformRecord()
        {
            foreach (var point in _points)
            {
                this.Cursor = new Cursor(Cursor.Current.Handle);
                Cursor.Position = new Point(point.X, point.Y);
            }
        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            PerformRecord();
        }
    }
```

Comment: What do you mean by list of points? Because when I press "Add coords" current mouse coords show on the viewlist.

Comment: Don't save it on the list, first save the points on a list like: var points = new List<Point>(); The Point class comes from System.Drawing, then bind the list in to viewlist and finaly iterate the points list.

Comment: Could you set an example of it please? So I can adapt it. I'm a little new to C#

Comment: Thanks a lot! I'll be waiting for it :D

Comment: So with this basically every time I click button1 I'll be recording 1 mouse coord form the screen and it'll save itself into the viewlist?

Comment: No, that doesn't implement viewlist. When you move the mouse save the coors on the list. You can use the viewlist in the same way but independent process or just bind the list into list view

Comment: Ok, what if I wanna manually add the coords I want my mouse to use for movement? (like I explained in main post).

Comment: The same, so when you click on "Add Coords" add a point into the list. Also you can add it ok the viewlist. You have to do it in both of them in the viewlist and in the list property.

Comment: Alright, got it, btw, does that list have to be located in a XML file or can it be stored inside this program?

Comment: Do you have to save it?

Comment: Not really, but I don't know how to call it back or where is it stored and how to bind it lol

Comment: The List object is like an array so it lives when you run the application

Comment: Oh ok, sorry, I'm moving from php and stuff so that array example was really useful. I read bindings MDSN but still can't manage to understand how to bind the List<Point> with listview1.

Comment: Doesn't matter just do both processes